# How to see color Ant output in MSYS/Git Bash?

Tags: ant, msys, git-bash

I'd like to use [AnsiColorLogger](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) to get color ouput from [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/).  I'm using [Git Bash](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) on Windows.

I tried:

```
$ ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger
```

but my output looks like:

```
Buildfile: c:\foo\build.xml
←[2;36m    [junit] Testsuite: org.foo.BarTest←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.188 sec←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] ←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] Testcase: testInherits took 0.175 sec←[m
←[2;36m    [junit]      FAILED←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] subdir not child←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: subdir not child←[m
←[2;36m    [junit]      at org.foo.BarTest.testInherits(BarTest.java:61)←[m
←[2;36m    [junit] ←[m
←[2;31m    [junit] Test org.foo.BarTest FAILED←[m
```

I know ANSI colors work, at least partially, in Git Bash because commands like `ls -ACF --color=auto` produce nicely colored output.

What's the trick for Ant?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After much Googling and experimentation, I combined several variations into a solution that works well for the particular combination of Git Bash, Ant and Windows.

Relaunch Git Bash after adding the following lines to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias ant='cant'
function cant {
  "ant" -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger "$@" \
      2>&1 | perl -pe 's/(?<=\e\[)2;//g'
}
```

**Git Bash Noob Tip:** `.bashrc` file, if it exists, lives in your home directory.  Here's how to create/edit it:

```
$ cd
$ notepad .bashrc &
```

Comment: For a general solution try creating a new file cant.bat beside your ant.bat within your ants bin folder with the following contents:
    @echo off
    call ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger %* 2>&1 | perl -pe "s/(?<=\e\[)2;//g"

Comment: No need to relaunch bash, after modifying `.bashrc`; just source it, in the running shell, like this: `. ~/.bashrc`, (or `source ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: notepad really is an abysmal choice of editor for creating or modifying `.bashrc`, (or indeed *any* shell script intended for consumption by either `bash.exe` or `sh.exe`), because it doesn't comprehend the LF only line ending style, which is the norm for such scripts.

Answer (score 7):

it's probably even easier to just set the environment variable ANT_ARGS.
e.g. just put this in your .bashrc:

```
export ANT_ARGS='-logger org.apache.tools.ant.listener.AnsiColorLogger'
```