# Colored output in Git Bash MINGW32 Msys

Tags: cucumber, msysgit, git-bash, msys

A similar question is already asked but that answers for `ANT` here [How to see color Ant output in MSYS/Git Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8129363/how-to-see-color-ant-output-in-msys-git-bash)

but I am running cucumber test cases.

Also I have tried tutorial given here https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon/, but no luck it didn't work

Comment: Sharing with @JustinKo may be he can answer.

Answer (score 1):

It works with git bash tricking cucumber into having ansicon installed, just put that into your `.bashrc`:

```sh
export ANSICON=1
```

This works, because git bash can handle bash color sequences and you just need to circumvent [cucumber's ansicolor check](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/blob/b1084c8391baf876fd3f9d3f9922098e48f8ad16/lib/cucumber/formatter/ansicolor.rb#L7).